# E.cancel loop in Visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I am making an server control application ( simple with some buttons to start/stop the server )
And when the user wants to close the application there will be prompted an confirm box.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    Dim response As Integer
    response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to stop the server", vbYesNo, "Stop Server ?")
    If response = vbYes Then
        Shell("cscript ""stop.vbs""", 1)
        Close()
    Else
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

That is the code I have now.
But when I start the application and close it with the X button or with "Close Window" I will be prompted with the question until I click on no, then it will close.
It's a loop and it stops when you first click on yes then on no.

Can someone help me with solving this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `Close()` call, since the `Form` is already closing. No need to do that.

Comment: Wow, thanks didn't notice that !
What a pitty I can't vote :D

Comment: I know it said wait 9 minutes I am going to do it after 1 minute now ;)

Comment: @Ahmed I don't think other answers will come up :-)

Comment: @BigYellowCactus you cannot accept an answer immediately after asking (there is a period of time you must wait). I think this is what Ahmed is referring to.